# Is amd64 the only 64-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I need to specifically install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop on a Dell PowerEdge server. The main site allows you to download 14.04 LTS. So I followed this link to 12.04:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

The problem is the download links are only available as i386 (which is the 32-bit version) or amd64 (which I assumed was for an AMD process, not an Intel). Should I still use amd64 download even if I am not using an AMD processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

amd64 em64t x86_64 mean all same.
For linux distro derived from debian use amd64 since origin(drbian) chose to use it.